# Javascirpt 18 decimal number for parameter?

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

I have created an 18 decimal crypto token in ethereum. When executing smart contract method from javascript for uint256 input parameter, how can I specify the number with 18 zeros? Because javascript doesn't support that large number.

here is my nodejs function

```
    let initiateAddLoyaltyTransaction = function (fromWallet, toWallet, companyName, amount, callback) {
    let functionName = 'transferWithAddLoyalty';
    amount = amount*1000000000000000000 ;
    let params = [fromWallet, toWallet, amount, companyName];
    W3JSR.prepareSignSend(config.ethereum.rinkeby.ABI_DEFINITION, config.ethereum.rinkeby.CONTRACT_ADDRESS, functionName,
        config.ethereum.rinkeby.WALLET_ADDRESS, privateKey, params, 10000000000).then((result, error) => {
        callback(result, error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Web3.js, which provides a library for just this use-case:

Web3.js v0.2 - [Big Number](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js)

Web3.js v1.0 - [BigNum](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#bn)

Converting a number to the equivalent number with 18 additional zeros is as easy as [calling a function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#towei):

```
web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');
> "1000000000000000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

web3.js using this big number library by default https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

then you can also use this lib in the node.js project to support the big number